# Sending a notification using firebase cloud Messaging sometimes sends the notification with image and sometime not

Tags: android, node.js, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an issue with firebase cloud messaging notification. I have implemented function that sends specific title, message and imageUrl and I made sure that the image size is less than 1mb as the documentation. But sometimes I see the image and sometime I don't see the image in the notification

and when I debug to check the notification object, it contains the imageUrl.

Here is my Implementation:

```
const notification = {
    title: data.title,
    body: data.message,
    ...(imageUrl && { imageUrl }),
  };

exports.notificationWithImg = async (registrationToken, notification) => {
  try {
    const response = await admin.messaging().sendMulticast({
      tokens: registrationToken,
      notification,
    });
    console.log("Notificatin response:", JSON.stringify(response));
    if (response.successCount > 0) {
      return {
        statusMessage: "SUCCESS",
        message: "Sent Successfully",
        statusCode: 200,
      };
    }
    if (response.failureCount > 0) {
      return {
        statusMessage: "ERROR",
        message: "Falure",
        statusCode: 400,
      };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error", error);
    return {
      statusMessage: "ERROR",
      message: "SERVER ERROR",
      statusCode: 400,
    };
  }
};
```

**Frontend**
using react-native-push-notification

```
PushNotification.localNotification({
            message: remoteMessage.notification.body,
            title: remoteMessage.notification.title,
            picture: remoteMessage.notification.android.imageUrl,
            priority: 'high',
            bigPictureUrl: remoteMessage.notification.android.imageUrl,
            smallIcon: remoteMessage.notification.android.imageUrl,
          });
```

Comment: Are you viewing the notification on an Android phone? If so, please share the Firebase service which handles the notification.

Comment: Hey @AbdullahZKhan I updated the answer with the frontend code